# Time drift and wrong timezone within NTP configuration

Tags: centos, ntp, scientific-linux, timezone, ntpd

We have 2 VLANs, each VLAN has a server that provides DHCP, DNS and NTP to its corresponding VLAN. These 3 servers take time from a local NTP server. Here is the configuration of NTP client and servers on each VLAN and the problem of each setup:

VLAN 1:

NTP Server (Scientific Linux 7.3)

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict xx.xx.xx.xx mask XX.XX.XX.XX nomodify notrap
```

NTP Client (Scientific Linux 7.3)

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
server yy.yy.yy.yy   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
```

This server is always drifting 3 hours forward despite the correct timezone.

VLAN 2:

NTP Server (Scientific Linux 6.4)

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
server 127.1.1.0 # local clock
fudge  127.127.1.0
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict xx.xx.xx.xx mask XX.XX.XX.XX nomodify notrap
```

NTP Client (Scientific Linux 6.4)

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
server yy.yy.yy.yy   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
```

Here I could not change the time zone. It should be `EET` but it is always `EEST` despite the `/etc/localtime` link value.

I have made sure that:

1. No firewall rules (`iptables -F`)
2. `ntpd` daemon is running and enabled (`chckonfig on`)
3. CentOS 7.x uses another time service called `chronyd` which blocks `ntpd` from startup. So I disabled it (Lost the source for this :( ).

After setting up these services, we synchronized them with our local NTP once. Through the DHCP configuration on each server we have `option ntp-servers xx.xx.xx.xx;` so the NTP information is distributed withing DHCP. I tried adding the local NTP server's address to the server's `/etc/ntp.conf` but the problem is still there.

Note that all servers are virtualized through VMWare ESXi.

Comment: What is your `/etc/localtime` linked to? Are all machines running on UTC system time (they should be)? Is the current time summer time or winter time where you are? EEST is UTC +3 hours.

Comment: It is linked to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/EET` but the `date` command always shows `EEST`. It is still winter time here, by the end of the week will be switching to EEST

Comment: If you are in Jordan, use `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Amman`. If you are in Syria, use `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Damascus`. Not all countries in the EET zone switches to summer time at the same time, so you'll need to be a bit more specific when you pick the time zone.

Comment: I tried it and nothing changed. The EET timezone used to work fine. That was the setup until like few weeks ago when we noticed drift in archived data timestamps.

Comment: Did the drifting machines get their system clocks set to EET too? The system clock should be in UTC.

Comment: Do you mean the regular time? If yes then yes, everything is in EET

Comment: Regarding the `Here I could not change the time zone. It should be EET but it is always EEST despite the /etc/localtime link value` how are you checking the timezone? NTP does not deal with timezones; perhaps you have a local $TZ variable?

Answer (score 3):

If your `/etc/localtime` is pointing to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/EET`, that timezone definition includes European Summer Time (= European DST) and between the last Sunday of March and the last Sunday of October, that timezone will be listed as EEST, not EET. And as of this writing, the changeover day was just yesterday...

You should read [VMware timekeeping best practices for Linux VMs](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1006427). 
In short:

- make sure the VMware Host is using correct time and timezone.
- if you're using NTP on guests:

  - make sure VMware Tools time synchronization is disabled
  - add `tinker panic 0` as the **first** line of /etc/ntp.conf
  - if there is a local clock definition like `server 127.127.1.0` in `ntp.conf`, **comment it out**.
  - put the hostnames or IP addresses of your NTP servers also into the `/etc/ntp/step-tickers` file to make your systems jump their clocks into correct time at boot as soon as network interfaces are activated and anything time-sensitive like databases has not yet been started.

Some pitfalls I've encountered:

- `/etc/adjtime` specifies what's the hardware clock expected to use: either UTC or LOCAL. Changing just the variable in `/etc/sysconfig/clock` won't necessarily do what you want. Make sure both places are in agreement, just to be safe.
- make sure your NTP servers are serving **correct UTC** time.
- when a system time is an exact number of hours off, first use `date -u` to verify that the system's idea of UTC time is correct. NTP only ever deals with UTC; any conversion error to local time is the fault of timezone settings.

Answer (score 0):

So after a struggle with these servers the issue has been resolved. Here are the details:

1. For the CentOS 7.X server, I disabled `ntpd` and used `chronyd` instead while maintaining `ntpd` on the clients. It seems that `chronyd` will be the supported NTP daemon from CentOS 7.X onwards. `chronyd` configuration requires only `server xx.xx.xx.xx prefer iburst` and `allow yy.yy.yy.yy/ZZ` in `/etc/chrony.conf`
2. For the CentOS 6.4 server I had to install new version of `tzdata` [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-updates-i386/tzdata-2018c-1.el6.noarch.rpm.html) and then link `/etc/localtime` to the corresponding timezone, in my case `Asia/Amman`

Some pitfalls I encounted:

- The nightmare error `no server suitable for synchronization found` on the CentOS 6.4 clients was resolved by stopping `ntpd`, running `ntpdate`, then starting `ntpd`.
- For some reason I don't remember, in the CentOS 6.4 I had to change `restrict 127.0.0.1` to  `restrict localhost`

Comment: If IPv6 is enabled, the NTP utilities in CentOS 6.4 can use it. And with the standard `/etc/gai.conf` settings and the default `/etc/hosts` file, applications looking for `localhost` will get the IPv6 `::1` in preference over IPv4 `127.0.0.1`. So any localhost connections may effectively happen over IPv6 rather than old IPv4, and that's why `restrict 127.0.0.1` may not allow localhost access as expected.